# Using CONTAINSTABLE with a FORMSOF and asterisk

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use `CONTAINSTABLE` with `FORMSOF` and searching for prefixes using the asterisk.  Is this possible, and if so what is the correct syntax?

My (wrong) attempt is:

```
CONTAINSTABLE( abc.Table, ColumnName, 'FORMSOF( THESAURUS, "wine*" OR "vine*" )')
```

What do I need to change to make this valid?

Comment: Can you show your whole query?

Comment: remove table from your query

Answer (score 0):

`CONTAINSTABLE` Doesnt take table name as parameter, it will only search on columns

It should be like:

```
CONTAINSTABLE(ColumnName, 'FORMSOF( THESAURUS, "wine*" OR "vine*" )')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in one term. From the docs:

```
<simple_term> ::=   
     { word | "phrase" }  
<prefix term> ::=   
     { "word*" | "phrase*" }   
<generation_term> ::=   
     FORMSOF ( { INFLECTIONAL | THESAURUS } , <simple_term> [ ,...n ] )
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If it was combined into one term it could be quite expensive, because you're asking the DB to find all words with the substring and then find all similar words to those. In your above example it would have to do that for both wine* and vine*. Ranking might be interesting too.

One workaround is to search twice, once using prefix and once using the thesaurus, then combine the results using your own ranking approach.

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINSTABLE **Can** take table name as parameter

```
CONTAINSTABLE   
( table , { column_name | ( column_list ) | * } , ' <contains_search_condition> '   
     [ , LANGUAGE language_term]   
  [ , top_n_by_rank ]   
)
```

See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)